# Android custom dialog null exception

Tags: android, xml, customdialog

line 102 and 104 null exception

i think imageView and textView id have problems.

Layout:

```
activity_main.xml
```

and `custom_view.xml` -- there are imageView and textView.

code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;


        switch(id) {
            case 0:
                dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //102:  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
                TextView text = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //104:  text.setText(");

                break;
        }

        return dialog;
    }
```

Log:

```
10-03 02:41:00.929: D/gralloc_goldfish(4372): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-03 02:47:07.159: D/gralloc_goldfish(4415): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-03 02:47:16.529: E/InputEventReceiver(4415): Exception dispatching input event.
10-03 02:47:16.529: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.example.hw3_new.MainActivity.onCreateDialog(MainActivity.java:102)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2989)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:976)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3082)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3041)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.example.hw3_new.MainActivity$CustomView.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:64)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-03 02:47:17.109: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4415):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.140: D/AndroidRuntime(4415): Shutting down VM
10-03 02:47:17.140: W/dalvikvm(4415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.example.hw3_new.MainActivity.onCreateDialog(MainActivity.java:102)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2989)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:976)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3082)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3041)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.example.hw3_new.MainActivity$CustomView.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:64)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-03 02:47:17.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 02:47:17.769: D/dalvikvm(4415): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 348K, 16% free 2671K/3176K, paused 110ms, total 120ms
10-03 02:47:21.018: I/Process(4415): Sending signal. PID: 4415 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What id do you pass to it ?

Comment: apparently there is no R.id.image in your activity_main layout.

Comment: R.id.image is in custom_view layout

Comment: i have two .xml file in the layout

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
        
</LinearLayout>

Comment: plz put the code as an edit to your original post instead of sharing it in comments.

Comment: I would like to see an actual question...

Comment: @user2841650 as you are saying your imageview in custom layout but your are including in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); try to add your imageview in activity_main xml.

Comment: @John R oh Thank you. you right! but i want to imageView in the custom_view.xml that is impossible??

Comment: @user2841650 you are using textview and imageview in both activity classes?

Comment: textView and imageview only appear in the custom dialog

Comment: @user2841650 i implement the following code its working. Thank you for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in your `activity_main.xml` -

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_view"/>
```

Hope its work.